# does a fact table always need to have a field for aggregate?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

When I was studying data warehouse modeling, the first thing I came into contact with was the `order` fact table, and the `product`, `user`, `date` dimension tables.

The `order` table will have `quantity`, `total_amount` field for aggregate. (Sum the units sold, sum the total_sales_amount)

So I'm considering does a fact table always need to have a field for aggregate?

I'm asking this because in my data warehouse designing, I'm trying to create a schema like this.

[image]

Is this a real standard multidimensional data model that meets Kimball's methodology?

Comment: *does a fact table always need to have a field for aggregate?* No. Example: fact table stores actual balance (not operation sums, but the balance resulted). How it can be aggregated?

Comment: @Akina so does a fact table have to have a **numeric** field? How do you think of the `fact_estate_opportunity` table shown in the attached image?